Inverse Z-Transform of $\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$ with ROC : |z|<1
I'm trying to Find the inverse Z-Transform of $\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$
My steps are as such :
$\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$ = $\frac{z^{-2}}{z^{-2}\cdot(1+z)^2}$ = $\frac{z^{-1}\cdot z^{-1}}{(1+z^{-1})^2}$ = $\frac{z^{-1}}{(1-(-1)\cdot z^{-1})^2}\cdot z^{-1}$
Using the known transformation in Page 2 number 8 of:
[Inverse Z-Transform ]
$  \frac{\alpha z^{-1}}{\left(1-\alpha z^{-1}\right)^2} \quad \rightarrow \quad -n \alpha^n u[-n-1] \quad  :\quad |z|<|\alpha|$
hence I'm getting $\alpha = -1$ ,  while having n-1 due to the $z^{-1}$ shifting ie using Time shifting Property in Page 1 , hence :
$(n-1)\cdot (-1)^{n-1} \cdot u[ -(n-1) - 1] $
Finally the Inverse Z-Transform is :
$(n-1)\cdot (-1)^{n-1} \cdot u[-n] $
My Issue is that this Answer seems to be incorrect , using new online tools I gotten an answer of :
$n \cdot (-1^{n-1} \cdot u[-n-1])$
This answer seems to match with My professor's .
I would appreciate if someone can tell me why the Time-shifting doe Not affect the first part in  $n$ rather than $n-1$ and in the last part of the step function in $u[-n-1]$ rather than $u[-(n-1)-1] = u[-n]$.

I'm not quite convinced you have an incorrect answer. Your professor's answer seems incorrect. The Z series associated with the signal
$$
h[n] = n\,(-1)^{n-1}\,u[-n-1]
$$
is,
$$
H(z) = -z + 2\,z^2 - 3\,z^3 + 4\,z^4 + \ldots
$$
This is convergent on the claimed ROC, but its transform is not $1/(1+z)^2$. To see this, we should verify that $(1+z)^2\,H(z) = 1$ as a formal power series. Observe that, however,
$$\begin{aligned}
(1 + 2\,z + z^2)\,H(z) 
&= (-z + 2\,z^2 - 3\,z^3 + 4\,z^4 + \ldots) \\
&\phantom{=}+ (-2\,z^2 + 4\,z^2 - 6\,z^4 + \ldots) + (-z^3 + 2\,z^4 + \ldots)\\
&= -z\\
\end{aligned}$$
That is, one would expect that
$$
H(z) = \frac{-z}{(1 + z)^2}
$$
Which, by the way, is consistent with the table of transforms and transform rules. Observe that,
$$
\frac{-z}{(1+z)^2} = \frac{(-1)\,z^{-1}}{(1 - (-1)\,z^{-1})^2}
$$
which you should immediately recognize from the transform table you provided. The only missing element is an additional $-1$ which can be absorbed into the power and shifted using the identity $(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^{n-1}$.
So, yeah, I actually think you have the correct answer. Let us validate that.
If we instead consider the Z series,
$$
G(z) = 1 - 2 z + 3\,z^2 - 4\,z^3 + 5\,z^4 + \ldots
$$
corresponding to your solution, we then observe that,
$$\begin{aligned}
(1 + 2\,z + z^2)\,G(z) 
&= (1 - 2 z + 3\,z^2 - 4\,z^3 + 5\,z^4 - 6\,z^5 + \ldots) \\
&\phantom{=}+ (2\,z - 4 z^2 + 6\,z^3 - 8\,z^4 + 10\,z^5 + \ldots) + (z^2 - 2 z^3 + 3\,z^4 - 4\,z^5 + 5\,z^6 + \ldots)\\
&= 1\\
\end{aligned}$$
